# Why a view (Activity indicator) not getting disappeared?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift3, uiactivityindicatorview

I've written almost identical code for another function and it works - but for some reason isn't working here. I just want to add this gray view with the activity indicator while the API is retrieving data from the server, and then hide it when the servers returns the data... the error label is updated appropriately, but the view never disappears... (grayLoadingView  -  this view contains the activity indicator)

```
 @objc private func signUpButtonPressed() {
    print("sign up pressed")

    if validateTextFields() {

        **//start activity indicator
        grayLoadingView.isHidden = false**

        createNewUser(username: usernameTextField.text!, email: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, completionHandler: { (message) in
            print("message-> \(message)")

            **//hide activity indicator
            self.grayLoadingView.isHidden = true**

            if message == "Account created successfully" {

                OperationQueue.main.addOperation {

                    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
                    let nextScreen = HomeScreenViewController()
                    nextScreen.username = self.usernameTextField.text!
                    let newNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: nextScreen)
                    self.present(newNavController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                }

            } else {

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    //display error message
                    self.errorLabel.isHidden = false
                    self.errorLabel.text = message
                }
            }
        })

    } else {

        print("empty")
    }

}
```

Comment: I would suggest that you might be saying `self.grayLoadingView.isHidden = true` on a background thread. Step out to the main queue to say it and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @matt You had to post your comment as an answer here as it is correct solution. By seeing your comment I just converted into answer.

Comment: @Monster  I intend to wait patiently for the OP to try what I suggested. If you want to be a thief that is between you and your conscience.

Comment: Sorry for that.. Just post your answer, I am removing my answer from here.. as this is your credit.

Comment: yeah, that seems to be the problem. Thanks, both of you. @matt